# pandas slicing and vstack interleaving a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The following code reads a csv file where data is in the format [A B C D E F G H D E F G H D E F G H ...]
And converts it to [A B C D E F G H] stacked in the same order

Here is the data source

```
http://web.mta.info/developers/data/nyct/turnstile/turnstile_110507.txt
```

Here is an example result from a single line

```
input_line = """A002,R051,02-00-00,05-21-11,00:00:00,REGULAR,003169391,001097585,05-21-11,04:00:00,REGULAR,003169415,001097588,05-21-11,08:00:00,REGULAR,003169431,001097607,05-21-11,12:00:00,REGULAR,003169506,001097686,05-21-11,16:00:00,REGULAR,003169693,001097734,05-21-11,20:00:00,REGULAR,003169998,001097769,05-22-11,00:00:00,REGULAR,003170119,001097792,05-22-11,04:00:00,REGULAR,003170146,001097801"""

output_lines = """
A002,R051,02-00-00,05-21-11,00:00:00,REGULAR,003169391,001097585
A002,R051,02-00-00,05-21-11,04:00:00,REGULAR,003169415,001097588
A002,R051,02-00-00,05-21-11,08:00:00,REGULAR,003169431,001097607
A002,R051,02-00-00,05-21-11,12:00:00,REGULAR,003169506,001097686
A002,R051,02-00-00,05-21-11,16:00:00,REGULAR,003169693,001097734
A002,R051,02-00-00,05-21-11,20:00:00,REGULAR,003169998,001097769
A002,R051,02-00-00,05-22-11,00:00:00,REGULAR,003170119,001097792
A002,R051,02-00-00,05-22-11,04:00:00,REGULAR,003170146,001097801
"""




for name in filenames:
    with open(name, "rb") as f, open("updated_" + name, "wb") as fw:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        writer = csv.writer(fw)
        for row in reader:
             header = row[0:3]
             readings = [row[x:x+5] for x in range(3, len(row), 5)]
             for elem in readings:
                 writer.writerow(header + elem)
```

[data wrangling](http://forums.udacity.com/questions/100160489/spolier-alert-a-working-solution-using-array-slices/100169976)

Is there a way to do this with pandas and dataframe slicing?

Comment: Can you give a concrete example of the input and the output? Because now I don't see how the code would convert `[A B C D E F G H D E F G H D E F G H ...]` to `[A B C D E F G H]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow can't download your full dataset. Is it for MTA internal use only?

Is the first, the second and the 3rdcol always to be the same in one file? That is the assumption for the following solution:

If each line contains the entries that have the same 1st to 3rd columns, a small modification is needed: basically it is to generate a dataframe for each line using the following method and then put them together into one.

If one line contains multiple ABCDEFGH, it will require some better methods.

```
In [68]:

df=input_line.split(',')
df_1stpt=df[:8]  #the leading row
df_2ndpt=np.array(df[8:]).reshape((-1,5)) #get the rest rows into the right shape
df_1stpt=pd.DataFrame(df_1stpt).T #create a dataframe containing the leading row
df_2ndpt=pd.DataFrame(df_2ndpt,columns=range(3,8)) #create a DF of the rest rows, with the right col idx
df_rst=df_1stpt.append(df_2ndpt, ignore_index=True) #put them together
df_rst.ix[:,[0,1,2]]=df_rst.ix[0,[0,1,2]].values #fill the nan's
In [69]:

print df_rst
      0     1         2         3         4        5          6          7
0  A002  R051  02-00-00  05-21-11  00:00:00  REGULAR  003169391  001097585
1  A002  R051  02-00-00  05-21-11  04:00:00  REGULAR  003169415  001097588
2  A002  R051  02-00-00  05-21-11  08:00:00  REGULAR  003169431  001097607
3  A002  R051  02-00-00  05-21-11  12:00:00  REGULAR  003169506  001097686
4  A002  R051  02-00-00  05-21-11  16:00:00  REGULAR  003169693  001097734
5  A002  R051  02-00-00  05-21-11  20:00:00  REGULAR  003169998  001097769
6  A002  R051  02-00-00  05-22-11  00:00:00  REGULAR  003170119  001097792
7  A002  R051  02-00-00  05-22-11  04:00:00  REGULAR  003170146  001097801

[8 rows x 8 columns]
```

Comment: It is a publicly available data set, just downloaded it fine here.